# GridView as DataTable source sorts only for the first time

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I implemented sorting on my GridView with a DataTable as DataSource by using code from [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx). However, my grid sorts for the first time when I click any column, and after that it does not sort on clicking any other column.

#### Code in the PageLoad() event -

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
      HView hv = new HView ();
      DataTable HTable = new DataTable("hTable");
      HTable = hv.FillTable();
      Session["hTable"] = HTable;
      GridView2.DataSource = Session["hTable"];
      GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

#### Code in the Sorting event -

```
    protected void GridView2_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable notesDT = Session["hTable"] as DataTable;
        if (notesDT != null)
        {                
            notesDT.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortDirection);                
            GridView2.DataSource = Session["hTable"];
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea of what I may be doing wrong?

#### EDIT: I just realized this. If I select a particular row, I have another view that gets populated with details about that row. When I view some rows details first before trying to sort any columns, then sorting works perfectly fine, any number of times. However, if I try to sort before selecting a row, it works only once.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `GridView2_Sorting` to see if it is called at all and whether or not `Session["hTable"]` is null?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I've checked, Session["hTable"] isn't null, it does sort for the first time .. After that as well, it isn't null, that's what is confusing me, nothing "seems" wrong ..

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `DataTable` as `DataSource` in the sorting event, but you should use the sorted view instead. Sorting the view won't change the sort order of the data in the table, just the order in the view.

```
protected void GridView2_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable notesDT = Session["hTable"] as DataTable;
    if (notesDT != null)
    {                
        notesDT.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortDirection);                
        GridView2.DataSource = notesDT.DefaultView;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Although that i've just noticed that you're using rhe same code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx).

You could also try to create a new DataTable from the view:

```
GridView2.DataSource = notesDT.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same code. I also tried the sorted view as datasource, however, the grid still remains unsorted.

Comment: @neuDev33: Strange. Try also creating another table from the sorted view as i've just added.

Comment: I tried this, still no sorting. The sort Expression and sort Direction are coming out correct when I checked in debug mode, I'm not sure what else could go wrong for this to not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need stored the data table into a session. Actually putting the entire data table into session is not a good idea at all. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) i referred to. Could you point me to a better way of doing it? Or I'd atleast like the current version to get working, since I'm facing issues with that as well.

Comment: @neuDev33: If ViewState is enabled you don't need to store the DataTable at all. Then you only need to pull data on first load and on actions like sorting,filtering,paging,updating and not on every postback.